# PHP Function with MySQL Query Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table which is populated with the results of a MySQL query. I need to insert an additional column into the table as a PHP function which generates a string based on the values of a field in the query (I think this is how the problem needs to be tackled). Is this possible? I've attempted setting the column as a variable and calling on that variable in the function (which isn't set as a user defined function in this code), but I must have done something wrong because the table did not populate at all.

```
$query1 = "SELECT `rank`.`term`,
                    `rank`.`acadplan`, 
                    `rank`.`projlvl`, `rank`.`gpa`, 
                    (SELECT COUNT(gpa) FROM `rank1` 
                    WHERE `rank1`.`term` = '{$term}'
                        AND `rank1`.`acadplan`='{$acadplan}' 
                        AND `rank1`.`projlvl`='{$projlvl}' 
                        AND `rank1`.`gpa` > `rank`.`gpa`) + 1 AS 'ranking',
                FROM `rank` 
                    WHERE `rank`.`term` ='{$term}'
                        AND `rank`.`acadplan`='{$acadplan}'  
                        AND `rank`.`projlvl`='{$projlvl}' 
                ORDER BY `rank`.`gpa` DESC";


$result = mysqli_query($query1);
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<th>Term</th>";
        echo "<th>Plan</th>";
        echo "<th>Level</th>";
        echo "<th>GPA</th>";
        echo "<th>Rank</th>";
        echo "<th>NEWCOL</th>";
    echo "<col width = '125'>";
    echo "<col width = '125'>";
    echo "<col width = '125'>";
    echo "<col width = '125'>";
    echo "<col width = '125'>";
    echo "<col width = '250'>";


$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

This is the function which needs to be executed:

```
if ($num_rows <=24) {
    switch ($num_rows) {
        case ($rank >=1 and $rank <=3):
            echo "1-3";
            break;
        case ($rank >=4 and $rank <=6):
            echo "4-6";
            break;
        case ($rank >=7 and $rank <=9):
            echo "7-9";
            break;
        case ($rank >=10 and $rank <=12):
            echo "10-12";
            break;
        case ($rank >=13 and $rank <=15):
            echo "13-15";
            break;
        case ($rank >=16 and $rank <=18):
            echo "16-18";
            break;
        case ($rank >=19 and $rank <=21):
            echo "19-21";
            break;
        case ($rank >=22 and $rank <=24):
            echo "22-24";
            break;
        }
    } elseif ($num_rows >=25 and $num_rows <=50) {
        echo "greater than 24";
    } elseif ($num_rows >=51 and $num_rows <=100) {
        echo "greater than 50";
    } elseif ($num_rows >=101 and $num_rows <=150) {
        echo "greater than 100";
    } elseif ($num_rows >=151 and $num_rows <=260) {
        echo "greater than 150";
    }
}
```

This is the table:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['term'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['acadplan'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['projlvl'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['gpa'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['ranking'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The `mysql_queryi($query1);` is a typo right ?

Comment: I think, it is a pre-SO correction xD `replace(/^mysql_/, /^mysqli_/) for SO snippets` ))

Comment: You should change `switch($num_rows)` to `switch(true)`.. and you can remove all lowerbound checks(except first)...

Comment: Take into consideration that if rank is for example equal to 15, it'll echo all the "13-15", "16-18", "19-21", "22-24", because you are not "break;"-ing it.

Comment: Also, what should be in that last column? You are executing query once, so the result will always be the same (for example for row count equal to 150) and so all the values in that column will be the same... Please add a comment about what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I'll explain a little further. The `ranking` field generates numbers from 1 - x. I want the last column to display a string based on the value in the `ranking` field. As you might be able to tell from the function itself, if the value in the `ranking` field is equal to 1, 2, or 3, I want the last column to display "1-3" and so on.

Comment: What about the elseif parts? They aren't connected to $rank.

Comment: I intend to have similar strings displayed for the elseif parts. For example, for the  first elseif, values in the ranking field equal to 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 are intended to display "1-5" in the last column. I've left those cases out simply because I didn't want the code to get too long on the page.  But if I'm not mistaken, they will be set up the same as the previous cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a solution like this one:

```
 function someFunction($rank, $num_rows) {
     if ($num_rows <=24) {
        switch (true) {
            case ($rank >= 1 AND $rank <=3):
                return "1-3";
            case ($rank <=6):
                return "4-6";
            case ($rank <=9):
                return "7-9";
            case ($rank <=12):
                return "10-12";
            case ($rank <=15):
                return "13-15";
            case ($rank <=18):
                return  "16-18";
            case ($rank <=21):
                return "19-21";
            case ($rank <=24):
                return "22-24";
        }
    } elseif ($num_rows >=25 and $num_rows <=50) {
         return "greater than 24";
    } elseif ($num_rows >=51 and $num_rows <=100) {
        return "greater than 50";
    } elseif ($num_rows >=101 and $num_rows <=150) {
        return "greater than 100";
    } elseif ($num_rows >=151 and $num_rows <=260) {
        return "greater than 150";
    }
    return "";
}
```

And then the table:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['term'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['acadplan'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['projlvl'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['gpa'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['ranking'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . someFunction($row['ranking'], $num_rows) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Edit:
You can use PHP in HTML tags like that:

```
<td><?php echo $row['ranking']; ?></td>
```

I find it preferrable way to use PHP values in my views. Of course strictly business logic should be separated if possible and not put in HTML tags.

Comment: This is just what I needed. After some googling, I think I understand when to use return vs echo (complete PHP newbie). Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you read a bit about using php in your html noy vice versa ( of course in php files). Ill  give you a clue in the edited answer